# Why my update image on Laravel 5.5 didn't work?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, model-view-controller, crud, edit

I have to do an edit data on my table master. User can edit the data and it work for the other, but when I change the image, it didn't change and didn't give an error when I update it. I use Laravel 5.5 and ere is the code I use :

This the controller for the update

```
public function update(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'nama_objek_edit' => 'required',
            'objek_lat_edit' => 'required',
            'objek_lng_edit' => 'required',
            'objek_deskripsi_edit' => 'required',
            'objek_pict_edit' => 'required'

        ]);


        $updateObjek = TbLokasi::where('id_lokasi', $request->id)->first();
        $updateObjek->lokasi_nama = $request->nama_objek_edit;
        $updateObjek->lokasi_lat = $request->objek_lat_edit;
        $updateObjek->lokasi_lng = $request->objek_lng_edit;
        $updateObjek->lokasi_desc = $request->objek_deskripsi_edit;
        if ($request->hasFile('lokasi_pict')) {
            $filePic   = $request->file('lokasi_pict');
            $extension = $filePic->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileName  = date('m-d-Y_', time()) . $request->lokasi_nama;
            // $filePic->move('/uluwatu_image/', $fileName . '.' . $extension, file_get_contents($request->file('objek_pict')->getRealPath()));
            $filePic->move('uluwatu_image/', $fileName . '.' . $extension);
            $updateObjek->lokasi_pict = 'uluwatu_image/' . $fileName . '.' . $extension;
        }

         $updateObjek->save();
        return redirect('/masterdata')->with('success', 'Data Berhasil Diubah');
    }
```

This the code when user want to change the image :

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-12">
        <div class="card" style="width:100%">
            <img src="{{ asset($updateobjek['lokasi_pict']) }}" style="width:100%" 
            alt="Card Image" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">Change Image</label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="objek_pict_edit" 
                name="objek_pict_edit">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the controller store for user adding new data :

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->hasFile('objek_wto')) {
            $filePic   = $request->file('objek_wto');
            $extension = $filePic->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileName  = 'pura-uluwatu';
            // $filePic->move('/uluwatu_image/', $fileName . '.' . $extension, file_get_contents($request->file('objek_pict')->getRealPath()));
            $filePic->move('marker/', $fileName . '.' . $extension);
        }

        // ObjekTable::create($request->all());

        $new_objek = new TbObjek();
        $new_objek->objek_nama = $request->objek_nama;
        $new_objek->objek_wto = 'marker/' . $fileName . '.' . $extension;
        $new_objek->objek_desc = $request->objek_desc;
        $new_objek->save();

        return redirect('masterdataobjek')->with('success', 'Data Berhasil Ditambah');
    }
```

> **[EditFormBlade.php](https://pastebin.pl/view/d9a899b6)**
>
> **[Controller](https://pastebin.pl/view/36b7bacf)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `$updateObjek->save();` before `return redirect('/masterdata')->with('success', 'Data Berhasil Diubah');`, so your change on Model is not saved.

Comment: So  debug,  when you submit form with image, will you get into condition `if ($request->hasFile('lokasi_pict')) ` ? Does your form have `enctype='multipart/form-data'`?  Is submited file moved to `uluwatu_image` directory? ...

Comment: i have try it, i only can change the image only once (in the first time) and the next it didn't change. here my full code for the controller (https://pastebin.pl/view/36b7bacf) and this is my form view (https://pastebin.pl/view/d9a899b6)